Having to "fix" ntfs drive every time turn on the computer
dekstop linux user here with some experience in linux for academic computing. In the spirit of being a greater linux supporter, I have changed my gaming computer for linux.
I have just installed pop_os in this machine, which has a secondary (no OS)  ntfs SSD drive installed, which stores my steam library. There is no dual boot in this machine.
For some wild reason, whenever I turn the computer on, I cannot access this secondary drive, with the files app telling me that 'an unknown error has occurred while mounting'.
If I run a 'repair disk' through the 'disks' app, it runs quickly and returns to its original state, no data loss. Likewise, running  sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1 quickly fix everything, with the main diagnosis being that
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... FAILED
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 3...OK

So, while functional, this is quite the pain to have to do everytime I log in the computer. It is especially cumbersome because I have to reconfigure steam to point to its library again and it takes multiple restarts to make it "see" the old disk.
Any way I can make that stop?

what happens when you run fsck /dev/sdb1 (before fixing it)

If you aren't dual-booting with Windows then DON'T use NTFS, it's as simples as that. For the purpose you want you should format it as EXT4 and automatically mount on boot, something that doesn't happen if you don't explicitly set it up to do. Many will be at this moment thinking "edit the fstab " but there's an easier and graphical way with the Disks tool available on your Pop_OS (or easily installable if it isn't).
